# How to update a node via OpenStreetMap PHP Api

Tags: php, openstreetmap

I'm trying to update a node that i've created before via the OSM PHP API. I've developed some functions that makes some CRUD operations by using the open street map API.

My update function is getting the node and the changeset id to make this operation, then i'm making a put request via this url `/api/0.6/node/#id`

```
    $ls_url_update_node = $this->get_api()->get_base_url() . "/api/0.6/node/".$this->get_id();
    $lo_requete = Request::put($ls_url_update_node);

    $ls_xml_node = $this->generate_xml($po_changeset);

    $lo_requete = Request::put($ls_url_update_node)
        ->sendsType('text/xml')
        ->addHeader('Authorization', $this->get_api()->get_authorization_header())
        ->body($ls_xml_node);
    $lo_response = $lo_requete->send();
```

The genarate_xml function try to generate a valid XML that respect the OSM specifications.

```
<osm>
 <node id="123" lat="..." lon="..." version="142" changeset="12"   user="fred" uid="123" visible="true" timestamp="2005-07-30T14:27:12+01:00">
  <tag k="note" v="Just a node"/>
   ...
 </node>
</osm>
```

The OSM Api returns this error message : Cannot parse valid node from xml string. Mayeb i've skip some differences between the creation and the update of a node. So any help please.

Comment: Please show us a complete example of a XML file you are trying to send.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send your request to `/api/0.6/changeset/create`. Also it must contain a `<changeset>` element. Please refer to the [API documentation for creating changesets](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6#Create:_PUT_.2Fapi.2F0.6.2Fchangeset.2Fcreate).

Adding elements is done by sending to `/api/0.6/[node|way|relation]/create`, see the [API documentation for creating elements](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6#Create:_PUT_.2Fapi.2F0.6.2F.5Bnode.7Cway.7Crelation.5D.2Fcreate). There you must refer a previously opened changeset.

If you still encounter problems it might be a good idea to use one of the popular OSM editors and look at their requests/responses via wireshark or a similar program.

Comment: Here the XML `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <osm version="0.6"> <node changeset="80115" version="4" id="4303111528" lat="48.619938" lon="7.727981">><tag k="opening_hours" v="Mo-Fr 07:45-12:00, 13:30-19:00; Sa 08:30-12:00, 13:30-18:30"/><tag k="shop" v="car_repair"/></node></osm>`